# Can't make Travis-CI work

Tags: ruby, testing, github, sinatra, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up Travis on this repo: https://github.com/lcguida/worksheet

I've put the travis.yml file there.

I've enabled the repository in my travis account (the "ON" button)

I've pushed some commits to see if it woukld trigger the tester.

I'm always getting this message in "My Repositories" tab: `You don't have any repos set up on Travis CI`

Here is my travis.yml file:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
  - 2.1.1
script: 'bundle exec rake test'
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the *same* mistake as you when starting on Travis :-)

The file name you need is `.travis.yml`

Note the first dot.

You can see what's wrong by looking at https://travis-ci.org/lcguida/worksheet/requests . . . where it repeatedly says "missing config"